# JQuery mousehover text on table td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery and Html table.

I have table columns with fixed width. But i dont want the text to wrap to next line or enlarge the table when td text exceeds the width.

Is it possible to display td value on hover of the mouse when text length is more than the td width?

If td value is as below:

```
abbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

then i have to display only:

```
abccccc......
```

and on mouse over i have to display entire text:

```
abbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

IS it possible? Please suggest me.

How can i calculate whether text length is exceeding the td length ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes possible. What have you tried so far???

Comment: Milind, am new to Jquery stuff...Please give me some idea..

Comment: first learn by going http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: I know Jquery basics..want to know the approach to calculate whether text width is exceeding the td width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery solution, with the benefit that you can limit the exact number of characters displayed, in CSS you can't.  If you don't want to damage your table structure, use a [tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/):

Link these files first:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

$("td").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();

    if(val.length > 8){
        $(this).attr("title", val);
        $(this).text(  clip( $(this).text() ) );
    }
});

// once the attributes have been set, execute the tootip:

$(document).tooltip();

// helper method
function clip(string){        
    return string.substr(0, 8) + "...";        
}
```

Comment: Gaurang, Thanks much for your answer. On mouse over it is expanding the column which in turn table structure will be changed and the table structure should not be changed.

Comment: Then you could easily use a [tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to display the overflowed text. In that you could remove the second function from my code `$("td").hover`, and add `title` attributes to each of your `td` dynamically if their length exceeds. I am editing my answer.

Comment: Basically tooltip is similar to the effect you get when you place a title attribute on an elemenent, it doesn't damage the structure of DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<span class='more'>abbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.more{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.more:hover{
    white-space:initial;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/NxcQu/)

**Updated** for `Table`,

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="max-width:100px">
           <span class='more'>abbcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** Change

```
.more:hover{
    white-space:initial;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

[Table demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/NxcQu/1/)

Comment: Rohan, thanks much for your answer. On mouse over, when the entire text is displayed, would it change table structure?

Comment: If you fix the `column width` then it will not change your `table structure`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with jquery checkout this -> https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Jos, Thanks for your answer. How can i calculate whether text length is exceeding the td length ?

Comment: You could create an html object containing your text and use jquery to get the width of that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the exact condition, but you can use the CSS and addClass/removeClass as below:

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span id="short" class="show"> gcccc...</span>
    <span id="full" class="hidden"> gcccccccccccccccccc </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#mydiv').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('#full').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('#short').addClass('hidden');
});

$('#mydiv').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).find('#short').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('#full').addClass('hidden');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWNTT/)

Answer (score 0):

consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/ueLha/

**HTML**

```
<table id="data_container" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><span>asdfadsfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfasdf</span></td>
    <td><span>kljkjlhklhlkhklhkhasdfasdfasdfadsfasdfas</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#data_container td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('span').width(20);
});

$('#data_container td').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('span').css('width', '100%');
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).find('span').css('width', '20px');
    }
);
```

**CSS**

```
span{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
#data_container td{width: 50%;}
```

Comment: jogesh, on mouse over it is changing table structure...which i dont want..Thank u so much for your answer.

Comment: @user755806 now its fixed, check the fiddle

Comment: @jogesh_pi What if the table was narrower ? http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/ueLha/2/

Comment: @GaurangTandon Any solution for this thread not work for the narrow table data, OP have to overflow it from the `<td>` if he want to fix the width.

Comment: @jogesh_pi A tooltip could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it may be possible with CSS only, provided you are willing to set some column widths fixed.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class='one'>Column One</th>
    <th class='two'>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='one'><span>Very long text which just goes on and on and on and on and ends.</span></td>
    <td class='two'>Epsilon Phi Ignatius Useful Strong Epsilon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='one'><span>1</span></td>
    <td class='two'>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
td.one {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td.one:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
td.one:hover span {
  min-width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}
td.two {
  width: auto;
}
```

Play around with this JSFiddle to adjust for your padding / widths etc:

https://jsfiddle.net/d233dbz7/